# C++ function name too long for perf

Tags: c++, std, perf

There's a function that takes 81% of my runtime according to `perf`. Unfortunately `perf` doesn't show the whole function name, only the following:

```
std::__detail::_Map_base<piece, std::pair<piece const, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<piece const, int> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equa
```

after `std::equa` I can't scroll any more to the right. How can I find out the whole function name to know which function it is? I am doing quite a few things with that map in the parent function, so it could be multiple things.

Comment: A cheat: if it takes _that_ much of your time, just attach a debugger and break at random.

Comment: Try `--no-demangle` to get the symbol name; it might be shorter and let you demangle it separately with c++filt or something.  Or `perf report` has a `-w` column width option, but the default is already 0 (unlimited).  Or maybe the `--gtk` option would be useful and let you resize your window or the columns.  Make the window wider than your full screen with alt+left to drag it around and alt+right to resize without clicking on a corner.  (Or whatever your window manager allows.)

Comment: First simple trick: use a full-screen window with the smallest font.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: I already am using a very small font with fullscreen but unfortunately this is all I got. And making the window wider than the screen is not possible for me on i3 (at least I don't know how).

Comment: @PeterCordes: I'm assuming `--no-demangle` is a compiler-flag. It might work as a workaround however I hope I can find a solution that keeps me from compiling and running the program again, because that takes quite a while.

Comment: --no-demangle is a perf option, please check the doc!

Comment: The part you show has only 143 characters or so, I can easily get 3 times that many in a fullscreen gnome-terminal using ctrl+- a few times, so I didn't expect you were already using a small font. This might depend on the screen resolution though.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Any good window manager will let you make a window larger than fullscreen by dragging it partly offscreen then resizing it some more.

Comment: @PeterCordes: You're right. `_ZNSt8__detail9_Map_baseI5pieceSt4pairIKS1_iESaIS4_ENS_10_Select1stESt8equal_toIS1_ESt4hashIS1_ENS_18_Mod_range_hashingENS_20_Default_ranged_ha` is a much better function name.

Comment: Ah, looks like it's still truncated, so `c++filt` won't decode it.  Looks like making your window wider is your best bet, either with or without demangling.  But you can still glean *some* info from the mangled symbol name, maybe / sort-of.  I think the actual function name comes first, and the types come later, so it's probably `__detail` or `Map_base::detail` or something like that.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Resizing the font to unreadable small and then copying the text into my editor did the trick. If you want to gather the points, please post that as an answer.
@PeterCordes: What about tiling window managers? And it was `std::__detail::_Map_base<[...]>::operator[]`.

Comment: Good point, I don't use a tiling WM so I forgot about that case.  I'm certainly willing to allow tiling WMs to qualify as "decent", so that shoots a hole in my claim :/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use the `--stdio` argument or simply pipe the output to a file you'll get full width lines with `perf report`. The pipe to a file trick (or just `| cat` if you still want it on stdout) works for many other utilities as well.

Comment: I think the parameter name has become `--stdio` meanwhile. Source: [man perf-report (5.10)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-report.1.html)

Comment: @jotrocken - perhaps it always was `--stdio`. I've updated my answer.